# Approximate a measurable set with an elementary set of equal measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be a measurable set.
we know that A is measurable iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an elementary set B such that $\mu(A \Delta B) <\varepsilon$
Where $A\Delta B$ is their symmetric difference.

For a given $\varepsilon$. Can we choose B such that $\mu(B) =\mu(A) $?

Comment: How are you defining "elementary set"?

Comment: A finite union of intervals. The intervals can be open, closed, ir half-open. See Definition 1 in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/245a-prologue-the-problem-of-measure/#more-4022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. We have $\mu (A\Delta B) \leq \mu (A\Delta C)+\mu (B\Delta C)$. So first make the first term less than $\epsilon /2$ and then increase or decrease the length of one of the intervals in $C$ to make $\mu (A)=\mu (B)$.  Use the fact that $|\mu(A)-\mu (C)| <\epsilon /2$.

Comment: nice, I had a similar idea yesterday when I thought about it, but I doubted myself